# threading object function c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

i'm having trouble with some threads in my program

I'm new in this thread material

I'm trying to start 2 threads on 2 different object function and it seems that they are not working at the same time (t1 works and t2 dont)..

edit:
the function of t1 works but t2 doesnt work. i checked t2 and t1, on their own they work, but together its like t1 prevents t2 from working

here is the main:

```
MessagesSender MSM=MessagesSender();
MSM.Push_user("ronik");
MSM.Push_user("ligal");
thread t1(&MessagesSender::DataRead,&MSM);
thread t2(&MessagesSender::DataSend, &MSM);
t1.join();
t2.join();
return 0;
```

here are is the function of t1:

```
void MessagesSender::DataRead()
{
    ifstream file_read;
    ofstream file_delete;
    string line;
    while (true)
    {
        file_read.open("data.txt"); // opens the file
        mtx.lock(); // locks the use of THOR
        while (getline(file_read, line)) // reads to THOR
        {
            cout << "im reading now" << endl;
            this->THOR.push(line);
        }
        mtx.unlock(); // unlock the use of THOR
        file_read.close(); // closes the file for reading
        file_delete.open("data.txt", ios::out | ios::trunc);/// opens the file and deletes the content/data
        file_delete.close(); // closes the file
        cout << "im sleeping now" << endl;
        print_THOR();
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(30)); // makes the thread sleep for 1 minute


    }

}
```

here is the function of t2:

```
void MessagesSender::DataSend()
{
    ofstream file_send;
    file_send.open("output.txt");
    set<string>::iterator SEI;
    while (true)
    {
        mtx.lock();
        while (!THOR.empty()) // while that prints all the THOR lines
        {
            for (SEI = ConUsers.begin(); SEI != ConUsers.end(); SEI++) /// to print the users
            {
                if (THOR.empty())
                {
                    break;
                }
                string p2(THOR.front());
                cout << "im sending now" << endl;
                file_send << *SEI << ": " << p2 << endl;
            }

        }
        mtx.unlock();
        THOR.push("im empty");
        print_THOR();
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(30));
    }

    file_send.close();

}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work" more clearly.  What, exactly, are you seeing?

Comment: @Donnie I'm new to stack overflow so sorry if mt question is not clear, the function of t1 works but t2 doesnt work. i checked t2 and t1, on their own they work, but together its like t1 prevents t2 from working

Comment: What is `MessagesSender`? What is `THOR`? Without seeing these definitions I don't think we can help. Also you need to specifically say what "work" and "doesn't work" mean. What behavior do you expect and what behavior are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this may be an issue of buffered streams. You are using the `std::cout` and calling `std::endl`. This causes the thread to pause until the data has been written to the console (slow). I've done this before and had the same problem. `t2` is getting hung up on the buffered stream, waiting for it to be cleared while `t1` has used it. Try replacing your `std::endl` with regular `'\n'` then just do a `std::cout << std::flush;` at the end of your program.